# Could not find method classpath() error

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

when I try to compile my project in Android Studio 3:

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

this is my build.gradle (Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
   applicationId "ir.chistaapplication.www.myapplication20"
   minSdkVersion 15
   targetSdkVersion 26
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
 }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put classpath dependencies inside `app/build.gradle`. Put them inside the `buildScript` dependencies in your project `build.gradle`

```
buildScript {
    dependencies  {
        // here
    }
}
```